# How to compress excel file using kendo-saveas in typescript?

Tags: .net, typescript, kendo-ui

Using kendo-saveas i am not able to download more than 1MB files.
So need to convert that file as ZIP file. I need some examples to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Kendo UI Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/save-files/introduction#server-proxy-implementations), you will need to implement a "Proxy" method. Generated Data will be sent through this Proxy method, and you will be able to compress the file using [any Zip algorithm or framework](https://www.ryadel.com/en/create-zip-file-archive-programmatically-actionresult-asp-net-core-mvc-c-sharp/).

Basic example:

```
public class HomeController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(string contentType, string base64, string fileName)
    {
      var fileContents = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);

      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
          using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
          {
              var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Fastest);
              using (var zipStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open()) zipStream.Write(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
          }
          return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Archive.zip");
      }
    }
}
```

And your View should be modified like...

```
<script>
    kendo.saveAs({
        // ...
        fileName: "test.txt",
        proxyURL: "@Url.Action("Save", "Home")"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I have tried to set proxy. But it is not working properly.

Comment: You see, that I can't do anything about the error description "it is not working properly". But a proxy is the only way, the client side feature has no compression options.

Comment: can you please suggest me that how to add headers for this proxy to saveAs?

Comment: You would need to show us some code and explain where the problem lies. You need to send HTTP Headers to `Save` action to get it working?

Comment: kendo.saveAs({
        dataURI: dataURI,
        fileName: "test.xlsx"
            proxyURL: 'path/to/Proxy',
            forceProxy: true,
            header: {
                Authorization: Identity.getAuthenticateToken()
            }
        });

Comment: but still getting "Authorization has been denied for this request." error

Comment: I don't think that `kendo.saveAs` is accepting a `headers` parameter

Comment: Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to support a specific part of the Question: Sending HTTP Header when using `kendo.saveAs`.

Accoding to [Excel Save-As Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/excel-export#saving-files-on-server), you can override `excelExport` Generation Function. You should be able to use this feature to send data to server for compression and return results.

Let's take the existing example from the page and update it, the part where the `$.post("/server/save", ...)` will be replaced with proxy call.

New part:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/server/proxy',
  headers: {
      'Authorization': Identity.getAuthenticateToken()
  },
  base64: base64,
  xhrFields: {
    responseType: 'blob'
  },
  fileName: "ExcelExport.xlsx",
  success: function(data) {
    // This is where we get the data, but we need to trigger browser's
    // download, lets fake it by creating a dummy anchor element and trigger it
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'download.zip';
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
});
```

Not quite sure if I got everything working though, this is untested :) But hopefully you get the point and could fix/update yourself.